# Stearyl Alcohol and Urea in my face cream?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, sawm, taharah, alcohol

After doing wudu, I put face cream that contains stearyl alcohol and urea. I also pray with that cream. I am also fasting (it is Ramadan now). Is it ok to use this cream or did my wudu/prayers/fast break?

I have a bad skin condition which requires me to put cream on my face 24 hours a day. If I don't use a face cream on my face, then it becomes red and dry and itchy. I finally found this cream that works on my face but is it halal?

I researched online and some people say it's ok and some people say it's not:

[Source1](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/768) [Source2](http://www.fiqhcouncilbirmingham.com/page/question/25) [Source3](http://www.sanha.co.za/a/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2312) [Source4](https://darululoomtt.net/creams-gels-urea/)

Thank you.

Comment: I added 4 sources to the question.

Comment: Be aware that we don't judge which view of Islam is more correct. And while fast reading these sources on my mobile I didn't get a clear distinction between the views on urea and I've got the impression none of them addresses sterile alcohol.

Comment: Source 1 and 2 say Urea in cream is prohibited. And Sources 3 and 4 say that it is permitted. I did not find any sources about Stearyl Alcohol so that is why I am asking here if anyone knows anything about it. I just want to know if Urea and Stearyl Alcohol is ok to use.